# How to use Auth0 provider with the new createBrowsereRouter in v6.4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, auth0

We're migrating to v6.4 and using `createRoutesFromElements` as suggested by the docs to migrate our routes to the new `createBrowserRouter` router.

Our setup looks something like this

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(--> our routes go here <--)
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Auth0 docs say that the Auth0 provider should be nested under the  provider. How could this be done with the new router?

We've tried wrapping the Auth provider around the Routes in `createRoutesFromElements` but doesn't work. Also tried to do this but we get an error.

```
<RouterProvider router={router} >
    <Auth0Provider />
</RouterProvider>
```

Can someone please help me understand where to place the Auth0 provider? Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems the `Auth0Provider` only needs to be rendered within a routing context provided by a router component. The `RouterProvider` doesn't take children JSX like that. I suggest rendering the `Auth0Provider` component on a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes) as part of the "create routes from elements" routes configuration. As a layout route `Auth0Provider` wraps an `Outlet` and provide its authentication context to all the nested routes of its sub-ReactTree.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Auth0ProviderLayout = () => (
  <Auth0Provider>
    <Outlet />
  </Auth0Provider>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<Auth0ProviderLayout />}>
      ... other nested routes ...
    </Route>
  )
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Working as a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add if you have a declarative routes object you can add the Auth0Provider to the route element.

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Auth0ProviderLayout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'styleguide',
        element: <StyleGuide />,
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: 'companies',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            element: <Navigate replace to="/companies/explore" />,
          },
          {
            path: 'explore/',
            element: <Companies />,
            loader: companiesLoader,
          },
          {
            path: 'filter/:filterAttribute/by/:filterValue',
            element: <CompaniesFiltered />,
            loader: filteredCompaniesLoader,
          },
          {
            path: 'favorites',
            element: <CompaniesFavorites />,
            loader: myCompaniesLoader,
          },
          {
            path: ':companyID',
            loader: companyLoader,
            element: <SingleCompany />,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'jobs',
        element: <Jobs />,
      },
      {
        path: 'contacts',
        element: <Contacts />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: The `Auth0ProviderLayout` is modified https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/react/basic-authentication#configure-a-react-authentication-provider to use `<Outlet />` instead of `{children}`.

Answer (score -1):

The Drew's example worked well, thanks. I did an improvement to work well with React Query + RR loaders:

```
const AppEntryPoint = () => {
  const router = useMemo(
    () =>
      createBrowserRouter(
        createRoutesFromElements(
          <Route element={<Auth0ProviderWithRedirect />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
              <Route
                path="/router-1"
                element={<Router01 />}
                loader={Router01Loader}
                errorElement={<ErrorPage />}
              />
              <Route path="/router-1/:id" element={<Router01Details />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<AuthPage />} />,
            </Route>
          </Route>,
        ),
      ),
    [],
  );
  return (
    <StrictMode>
      <AppProviders>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </AppProviders>
    </StrictMode>
  );
};
```