# Cannot update a component while rendering a different component. To locate the bad setState() call follow the stack trace as described

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I've scouted for an answer but in most cases its just badly spelling or misplacing the call which I believe its not the case here. It's React logic I somehow find hard to understand.

I'm using [This type of React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) and I'm trying to provide `Outlet` with a set of data that can be changed while the user is on a **children** website. I decided to try [React Providers](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext) instead of React-Router tool [useOutletContext](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) because the data provided can grow over time. I decided to follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73938067/18298804) approach.

So here is the code.
App.jsx

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Routing />
      </Suspense>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```

Routing.jsx

```
const BrowserRouter = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" name="home" element={<HomePage />}>
      <Route path="device" name="device" element={<DevicePage />}>
        <Route path=":id" element={<DeviceList />}></Route>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<Roadblock.site404 />} />
    </Route>,
  ),
)

export default const Routing = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={BrowserRouter} fallbackElement={<Loading />} />
}
```

DevicePage.jsx

```
export default function DevicePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <DeviceContent />
    </>
  )
}
```

DeviceContent.jsx

```
export default function DeviceContent() {
  return (
    <>
      <DeviceProvider>
        <Outlet />
      </DeviceProvider>
    </>
  )
}
```

DeviceProvider.jsx

```
export const DeviceContext = createContext()

export function DeviceProvider({ children }) {
  const [device, setDevice] = useState(null)

  const addDevice = () => {
    setDevice(data)
  }

  const deviceContext = {
    device,
    addDevice,
  }

  return <DeviceContext.Provider value={deviceContext}>{children}</DeviceContext.Provider>
}
```

and here is the `Outlet` DeviceList.jsx called in `Route`

```
export default function DeviceList() {
  const { device, addDevice } = useContext(DeviceContext)

  addDevice('1')
  console.log(device)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{device}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Error code

> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Cannot update a component
> (`DeviceProvider`) while     rendering a different component
> (`DeviceList`). To locate the bad setState() call inside
> `DeviceList`, follow the stack[...]

**Question**: What behavior/logic is causing the problem and how can I understand and avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeviceList` is enqueueing a state update outside the React component lifecycle. In other words, as an ***unintentional*** side-effect. Move the `addDevice` call to a `useEffect` hook so it's an ***intentional*** side-effect.

Example:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function DeviceList() {
  const { device, addDevice } = useContext(DeviceContext);

  // Update device state when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    addDevice('1');
  }, []);

  // Log device state updates
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(device);
  }, [device]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{device}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I've seen your answer somewhere with useEffect but I ignored it due to rule that useEffect shouldn't be abuse due to it re-render effect. Could you elaborate "enqueueing a state update outside the React component lifecycle" ?

Comment: @Coffeeye This is in no way an abuse of the `useEffect` hook, far from it. The entire function body of a React function component is the "render method". React *may potentially* call this function to "render" any number of times to compute a diff for reconciliation. This is why unintentional side-effects should be avoided. See this outdated (*sorry*) [diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) of the React component lifecycle from the legacy [docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

Comment: @Coffeeye and note that "render" occurs during the Render Phase and may be paused, aborted, or restarted by React while the `useEffect` hook's synonymous counterparts `componentDidMount`/`componentDidUpdate` occur during the Commit Phase that is called exactly once per render cycle when the next computed UI is committed to the DOM and rendered to the screen. There is also the [Lifecycle of Reactive Effects](https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects) available in the current React documentation.

Comment: Thanks again. The way you described the problem helped me understand what was going on, but I still think it's the wrong way to solve problems. You shouldn't use the useEffect hook when it can be avoided and only use it when its logic suits you perfectly. As I mentioned, I want the user to change the values inside the children, which will cause the component to be render multiple times during its lifetime. Let's say I want addDevice to increment. This would give me an increase of 2 instead of 1 because the page renders twice due to some standard implications. But I understand its just example.

Comment: As a workaround, you led me to the solution, and I just added a button to solve the problem in this particular example, with a function call instead of using a hook.

Comment: @Coffeeye I don't understand where you got the notion that using the `useEffect` hook should be avoided, it's simply used to issue side-effects from an otherwise pure function. What you describe with double incrementing a count is likely the result of rendering your app into a [StrictMode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode) component which double-mounts components and double-invokes specific functions as a way to help surface logical bugs in your code. This occurs only in non-production builds.

Comment: @Coffeeye And OFC yes, using callback function with a button or some other UI interaction is also a sufficient method of issuing the state update as an intentional side-effect.